# How can I create a tab to display stuff onmouseover?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, css

I would like to create this tab that when you point with your mouse on it it displays for instance a vertical list of redirections(links, etc.), and when you move your mouse away it will be hidden again, seems kinda' hard :O

How do I do that, please? (I'm programming with c# if it has anything to do with it).
Take your time and thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be sure - you want kind of javascript-solution like

```
$("#hover").mouseover(function(){$(".message").show()});
$("#hover").mouseleave(function(){$(".message").hide()});
```

for something like

```
<div id="hover">hover here</div>
<div class="message" style="display:none;">Message</div>
```

or something else?

In case, this would mean: create e.g. a div with an id, another div with e.g. a class (could also be an id but just for variety ;) ), set the message with css to `display: none;` and bind jquery `mouseover()` and `mouseleave()` event-handlers to the #hover-element calling the jquery functions `show()` and `hide()`.

And for reference: [api.jquery.com/mouseover/](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)  [api.jquery.com/show/](http://api.jquery.com/show/)  [api.jquery.com/hide/](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

In case you want it as pure CSS, it's possible to use the pseudo-element `:hover` for the element instead:

```
<div id="hover">hover here</div>
<div class="message">Message</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .message {
    display: none;
   }

  #hover:hover + div.message {
   display: block;
  }
```

but this will only work when the element to display follows directly behind the element that will display the message when hovered.

Comment: Would it display a vertical list of stuff? CHeck out this website http://www.calm.com . You can notice once you point your mouse on one of these icons this list pops out. I'm looking for something similar, vertical, with no icon but just simple text or anything, and obviously alot less complex. Oh and I'm actually not workring with jquery.

Comment: Yes, it's the same functionality, but they did it with pure css / HTML5. Can add that to the answer. It's "only" a matter of css-styling to have it to look like that. As most browsers can handle HTML5 nowadays, it's possible to handle it like that but I used to have fallbacks with jquery just to be on the safe side.